# Vertically center a button inside a responsive container with pure CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

So I want to make this [thumbnail effect](http://jsfiddle.net/5hKXX/).

```
$(window).resize(setThumbHeight);
$(window).resize(centerBtn);
```

[SEE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5hKXX/)

As you can see I wrote some JQuery to set the container height and center the btn, which I think is pretty dumb.

I have a few questions:
1. How can I maintain the aspect ratio of the container without using JQuery.
2. How could I center the button vertically inside the container using pure CSS? (It seems someone had it done with table and table-cell)
3. Why background url is not working? (I have the line commented out in the CSS.)

Thanks guys.

Comment: Given that you have a dependency on jQuery already, why is a pure CSS solution necessary?

Comment: IDK. maybe it's not important. I just don't feel comfortable about the fact I need to use some code to vertically center something. I still have 2 other questions though.

Comment: This can be done with just CSS no need to overcomplicate with Javascript

Comment: Table solution http://jsfiddle.net/46psK/186/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center an element vertically with this trick:

change value of margin if you change width or height of your button.

-17px is half of height and -30px is half of width

```
.thumbnail-mask .btn{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-17px -30px;
}
```

and for zoom on picture you can use this:

```
.my-thumbnail:hover img{
     -webkit-transform:scale(1.5);
     -moz-transform:scale(1.5);
     -o-transform:scale(1.5);
     -ms-transform:scale(1.5);
     transform:scale(1.5);
 }
```

and if you want display your picture with background css property, you must have height on your container `.my-thumbnail`.

Comment: Dude, that's smart. I didn't think of that. I wanted to use scale at first. But It had some weird effect on my navbar, which I believe is a render bug. So, I decided to just stick with simple transition. But hey, one less JQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/5hKXX/2/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple cross-browser method to achieve what you're looking to do:

http://codepen.io/aecend/pen/KEvBa

I didn't bother with any of the CSS transitions, just focused on the centering. To maintain the container dimensions, only set the width of the outer thumbnail container, the height will automatically flex to fit. Also, the background url does seem to be working, the image itself was covering the background in your fiddle.

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  <div class="mask center-in-container"></div>
  <button class="button center-in-container">Enter</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thumbnail {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.center-in-container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  display: none;
}
.mask {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  display: none;
}
.thumbnail:hover .button {
  display: block;
}
.thumbnail:hover .mask {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hashbug,

Aside from a JavaScript method, which, you have employed - there are no **dynamic**, cross-browser compatible solutions for what you are attempting to do.

If you still do not wish to use JavaScript, and are O.K. with this not working cross-browser, then you may want to take a look at CSS3's flexbox.  As I said the flexbox is not supported by all browser versions yet, you can find out which here: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).  I made a fiddle to show your solution updated with flexbox here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jpatterson69/z8uCK/

```
.thumbnail-mask {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);    
    opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

I did not include any of the "hacks" as other users have posted because they generally will cause you much more strife than is needed - your solution is the easiest compared to these.  May I ask why you need to use the flexbox?

Comment: Wow. Never heard of those attributes before. Good to know. I don't know why. I just don't like to use too many codes for a design job. If you ever aligned two objects in PS or AI, you know how easy that is. And I think that should be supported in the browser too.

Comment: I agree.  I have been a Front-End / UI / UX developer for over 10 years and I still get angry about it.  As a human being - there are too many options for a lot of web/technology things these days.  It's part of the problem. //End rant

Comment: I should probably add that aecend's method will work, just not in all versions of every browser - and that includes a very large majority of them.  Just want to be clear, your javascript solution is going to reach the widest audience and work the best.

Comment: I also just read Cam's comment on your original post.  It can certainly be done with CSS, but it's debatable whether CSS is the best solution.

Comment: Always good to have someone who shares the same feeling. :) Thanks for the heads up.