# Vertically align middle in Bootstrap column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, vertical-alignment

In a Bootstrap carousel item, I have a row of images nested in Bootstrap columns. Their height varies according to the width of columns. In the same row, there are also carousel controls LEFT and RIGHT for changing the items of the carousel.

I need to have the controls left (<) and right (>) vertically centered to the row. How can this be acomplished?
I tried to remove the row class and use the dislay: table and table-cell, which aligned controls vertically, but whole responsiveness was lost.

Example here: http://testabc.borec.cz/

HTML (carousel):

```
<div id="monthly-tips" class="carousel slide showcase showcase-1 text-center"><!-- class of slide for animation -->
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item container-fluid active">

        <div class="row" style="display: flex;
    align-items: center;">          
          <div class="col-xs-1 nopadding">
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#monthly-tips" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="gi gi-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5 col-md-3">
            <img src="./img/books/syn-spravce-sirotcince.jpg" class="envelope js-book1" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-5 col-md-4">
            <img src="./img/books/tanec-s-nepritelem.jpg" class="envelope js-book2" alt="" />
          </div>    
          <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-3">
            <img src="./img/books/syn-spravce-sirotcince.jpg" class="envelope js-book1" alt="" />
          </div>      
          <div class="col-xs-1 nopadding">
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#monthly-tips" data-slide="next">
              <span class="gi gi-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">          
          <div class="col-xs-1 nopadding"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5 col-md-3">
            <span class="bottom-shadow"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-5 col-md-4">
            <span class="bottom-shadow"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-3">
            <span class="bottom-shadow"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 nopadding"></div>
        </div>  

        <div class="row info-holder">

          <div class="col-xs-1 nopadding"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5 col-md-3">
            <p class="book-title">Syn správce sirotčince</p>
            <p class="book-author">Adam Johnson</p>
          </div>
          <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-5 col-md-4">
            <p class="book-title">Tanec s nepřítelem</p>
            <p class="book-author">Ruta Sepetysová</p>
          </div>
          <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-3">
            <p class="book-title">Tanec s nepřítelem</p>
            <p class="book-author">Ruta Sepetysová</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-1 nopadding"></div>
        </div>        
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" alt="" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Caption text here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- carousel monthly-tips -->
```

Comment: this code does not duplicate your problem. http://www.bootply.com/f8prSrZPo5

Comment: I changed the code, previous one was just a part to illustrate the used structure as the rest could be seen on the page example.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a new css property `align-items` on your `.row` container like this :

CSS :

```
.row { // add a new class to your row and target your newest class
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's a new property css3, but if you want browser compatibility you can use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616821/vertically-center-a-button-inside-a-responsive-container-with-pure-css/23617615#23617615

Comment: @JoffreyMaheo, I would avoid the solution with absolute positioning because it messes with the responsiveness of Bootstrap columns. Absolutely positioned items are moved out of the flow of the DOM and Bootstrap columns will not be able to adapt to accomodate the width of these items.

Comment: This broke the responsiveness of my `.row` (on Chrome at least)