# Vertically centre the contents of a bootstrap push/pull column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to vertically centre the contents of a bootstrap column, where the columns are arranged using the bootstrap `col-sm-push-*` and `col-sm-pull-*` classes. The normal `table` / `table-cell` method doesn't work.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-pull-5 text-center">
      <p>
        should be v-centered
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/jitogoqaruha/1/edit

Update: tweaked to make it more obvious what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I played with this some... 
.text-center p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;      
} 
May i suggest changing your demo with some stuff under it so its easier to reference if the text is actually vertically centering

Comment: Something like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162020/vertically-align-middle-in-bootstrap-column/25162229#25162229

Comment: Oh, how I'd love to use flex, but it needs browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're okay with IE8 getting a none vertically centered look, here's another approach.

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/tiwic/1/edit

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/900x600">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-5 center-box">
      <div class="content">
        I want this to be vertically centered. I have 
        to use the col-sm-push and col-sm-pull classes
        to make sure the text is below the image on
        mobiles.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width:768px) { 
    .center-box {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    .center-box:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        padding-top: 50%;
        padding-top:0%\9; /*ie8 will just be at the top */

    }

    .center-box > .content {
        top: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: center;
        position: relative;
        transform: translateY(-50%); /* ie9 and up only */
    }

}


/* -------- combines 


http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html


http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/ -- which doesn't work without a height

--------- */
```

Answer (score 1):

You **still** could use `display:table` and `direction` to overwrite some bootstrap rules:
http://jsbin.com/tokixojojuru/1/edit

```
.container {
  display:table;
  direction:rtl;
}
.row>div {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  direction:ltr;/*reset to your regular flow */
}
```

Comment: This is cool. Just put in a min-width media query and isolate the classes to be more specific.